# A question about Lie group homomorphisms

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

Suppose I have a Lie group $G$ and a Lie homomorphism $ \phi : G \rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Can $ \phi $ be viewed as some sort of representation of $G$?

Can anyone make this rigorous for me please?
Thanks.

Comment: @TedShifrin: You mean $n$-dimensional representation?

Comment: @Selena: As Ted notes this is one way of *defining* what a representation is.  Given that you're asking this question I suspect a representation to you is defined in some other way.  If you let us know what that is maybe we can bridge the gap.

Comment: @Jim It was defined as an action; but I see how it all leads to the same place... I guess I was just confused as I am fairly new to the idea of a representation.

Comment: Oops, I totally missed the $n$. Yes, by definition, this is an $n$-dimensional representation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another common way of defining a representation is that it's a vector space $V$ together with a smooth map $G \times V \to V$ that satisfies the axioms of an action by linear transformations.

First convince yourself that the canonical action $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb R) \times \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is smooth.  Then given $\phi$ as above you have the map
$$G \times \mathbb R^n \xrightarrow{\phi\times\operatorname{id}}\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb R) \times \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$$
which is a composition of smooth maps, so it's smooth and gives the action that you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A group representation is a group homomorphism $\phi:G\rightarrow \operatorname{GL}(V)$, where $V$ is a vector space.  If we take $V=\mathbb{R}^n$, we see that $\operatorname{GL}(V)=\operatorname{GL}_n\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$.  So, what you have got there is a real representation of finite dimension.

Comment: Well, in commets the OP mentions that representations were defined to her as actions, which I imagine means as maps $G\times V\to V$ satisfying the axioms that one knows. So there is a (little) work to be done here.